# Если "книга IV глава первая" расположились внутри предложения, какие нужны знаки? если нужны?

Tags: пунктуация

> Перед вами **цитата из книги IV главы первой**: «Происхождение трёх
>   ордеров и пропорции коринфской капители». Современник императора
>   Августа, Витрувий собрал в свой труд накопленные Римом к первому веку
>   знания о строительстве и проведении инженерных работ. «Десять книг об
>   архитектуре» стали учебником для человечества на тысячелетие. Сама
>   эпоха Возрождения берет разбег от дня публикации этой книги в 1414
>   году...

После императора Августа у автора было тире; не напортачила ли я с нарисованной мной запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы назвала «главу первую» уточняющим дополнением, так что её нужно обособить с двух сторон. Также у меня возник вопрос по поводу «Происхождения трёх ордеров и пропорции коринфской капители». На саму цитату непохоже. Это название главы, книги или цикла книг? В любом случае, двоеточие там не к месту.

1. Если это название главы: *Перед вами цитата из книги IV, главы первой «Происхождение трёх ордеров и пропорции коринфской капители»...*
2. Если это название книги: *Перед вами цитата из книги IV «Происхождение трёх ордеров и пропорции коринфской капители», главы первой...*
3. Если это название цикла книг: *Перед вами цитата из книги IV, главы первой «Происхождения трёх ордеров и пропорции коринфской капители»...*

Цитату нужно взять в кавычки, перед ней поставить двоеточие.

Витрувий - это приложение, его нужно выделить с двух сторон запятыми или тире. Я бы поставила запятые.

*«Современник императора Августа, Витрувий, собрал в свой труд...»*

Comment: **1.** Цитата - в рамочке и затейливым шрифтом - была *до*. **2.** Верен пункт 1. **3.** За Витрувия, так же как и за "главу", отделяемую от "книги", - гран мерси.

Comment: Не, а где мне пятёрка за такой умопомрачительно интересный вопрос? Так нечестно. Плакайу...Т_Т